# how to validate the answer of type radio using ajax or jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having a problem in validating and displaying whether the given answer is correct or not. 
The code should check the result and display green div which is hidden when 
answer is correct, and when the answer is wrong red div should be displayed.

Here is my ajax code:

```
function x() {
    var rads = document.getElementsByName("rads");
    for ( var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++ ) {
        if ( rads[i].checked ){
            var val = rads[i].value;
            return val;
        }
    }
}

function post_answer(){
    var p = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var id = document.getElementById('qid').value;
    var url = "userAnswers.php";
    var vars = "qid="+id+"&radio="+x();
    p.open("POST", url, true);
    p.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    p.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(p.readyState == 4 && p.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '';
        var url = 'quiz.php?question=<?php echo $next; ?>';
        window.location = url;
        }
    }

    p.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("status")
}
```

php code:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] != ""){
    $answer = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $_POST['radio']);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['answer_array']) || count($_SESSION['answer_array']) < 1){
        $_SESSION['answer_array'] = array($answer);
    }else{
        array_push($_SESSION['answer_array'], $answer);
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['qid']) && $_POST['qid'] != ""){
    $qid = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $_POST['qid']);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['qid_array']) || count($_SESSION['qid_array']) < 1){
            $_SESSION['qid_array'] = array($qid);
    }else{
        array_push($_SESSION['qid_array'], $qid);
    }

    $_SESSION['lastQuestion'] = $qid;
}
```

The problem is that I'am not able to display whether the answer is corect or not.

It should display the .$answer. is not correct. plz help me 
thanx in advance

Comment: I tried my best to edit your question and make it more readable. Please pay more attention to formatting and punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I am not good in PHP! But I can tell you what to do.
You can write a div for the Radio button with some specific ID or class name as: `<div id="ajax-result"><input type="radio" /></div>`
And just simply write the result that you get from the Ajax!
If the result of that post from ajax is radio_checked then the radio will be checked instead it will remain same!